# Why am unable to take the test in editText using the getText().toString()

Tags: textview, android-edittext, user-input, gettext, settext

[Unable to get the Text in the editText](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsPzX.jpg)

I tried to get the Text in editText once the user Clicks the button and I tried to set that text into a TextView..but after entering the input when the user presses the button,the TextView is hidden,I have also tried to display that message using Toast,but it doesn't show anything.. please guide me through this